# Retrieving a ConnectionString through System.Configuration Throws Exception

Tags: c#, connection-string

In my C# application, i am trying to connect to a DataConnection.
The application is just a simple Login form but as soon as the user clicks the login button, it throws an exception error referencing the Connection String. Can anyone help?

```
public void userLoginSuccessfull()
{
    try
    {
        //////////////////////////////////
        // This line is throwing the error
        //////////////////////////////////
        string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

        if (txtUsername.Text != "" & txtPassword.Text != "")
        {
            string queryText = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM Users 
                     WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password";

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
                int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result > 0)
                {
                    loadUserForm();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(ee.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

This is the error

> 'EnviroWaste Job Logger.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: EnviroWaste Job Logger.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\listm\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\EnviroWaste Job Logger\EnviroWaste Job
>   Logger\bin\Debug\EnviroWaste Job Logger.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in  System.Configuration.dll
>
> Configuration system failed to initialize
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

The connection string looks like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UsersDatabase.mdf;Integr‌​ated Security=True"
```

Comment: You only have part of the error, it would help if we knew the line of the error and the exception that was thrown.

Comment: When you receive an exception, the *first* thing you should do is *read the error message*.

Comment: And if your error involves an exception string, *include it in the question* **without the password**.

Comment: Also, side note... You're storing user passwords in plain text.  ***Never do that.***  It's grossly irresponsible to your users.  Passwords should be hashed and should never be retrievable, not even by you the programmer.

Comment: @David The world has been developing web applications for what, 20 years now, and people *still don't @#$%ing get it*.

Comment: What does your connection string from your app.config/web.config look like?

Comment: @Tremmors The connection string looks like this: connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UsersDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Does that database exist?

Comment: @David - This is just a small test application as Im still teaching myself C# and are still in the very beginner stages. I tried pasting the exception error message. Am i reading the wrong thing here?

Comment: @MattList:  You pasted the stack trace, not the message.  That `ee` object in your `catch` block has a `Message` property.  Don't ignore it.  It might also have lots of other useful information that shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: @ThreeValueLogic Yes the database definitely exists.

Comment: Also, as a side note, please do not ever write `catch (Exception ee)` - catching every exception is bad. It's like running with scissors - you're going to get hurt. It just swallows up errors that you might find very useful if they are thrown.

Comment: @David I have changed the question to display the message and not the stack trace. Its that how it should look? From what i can see, The Configuration system failed to initalize.

Comment: @MattList: That message could mean a various number of things, I'm afraid.  But the good news is that the message ("Configuration system failed to initialize") gives you something to search on Google.  It looks like there are a number of other questions on Stack Overflow related to that, you may be able to find something.

Answer (score 2):

The error you got relates to a configuration file that has incorrect content. Most likely, your `app.config` (if desktop) or `web.config` (if web app) file the following error:

> It does not have as its **first** element the `<configSections>` element.

Check that file and make sure it looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- Section groups, and stuff like userSettings, etc  -->
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UsersDatabase.mdf;Integr‌​ated Security=True"/>
    </connectionStrings>

    <!-- Possibly other stuff  -->

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into the same problem. The explanation Alex provided gives a clue into the issue however it is not enough.

The app.config apparently expects the elements to appear in a certain order.

Therefore, in app.config, right after <configuration>, the first section MUST be:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- Section groups, and stuff like userSettings, etc  -->
</configSections>
```

Followed by the

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="...whatever is here..."/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And then comes the rest.

In my case, I had:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
```

As the very first element after <config&gt.

All I needed to was to move the <system.data> section and place it AFTER the <connectionStrings>, in order to respect the order that VS needs.

So in addition to needing to have the <configSections> before <connectionString> these must also be the two first sections right after <config&gt. This is what fixed it for me.